# sql query regarding insert seq no?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Name,Age,Seq

G,30,1
G,31,1
K,28,3
K,29,3
k,28,3
V,,4
V,28,4
```

I've table with columns `Name, Age, Seq` when I insert the first row like this

```
G, 30, 1
```

now I want whenever i insert the second row with same seq no. (1) in above row
   the row should replace with the existing row.

like I'm inserting `G,32,1` now the existing record `G, 30, 1` should be replace by 
   `G, 32, 1` because seq. (1) is matched.

how can i achieve this. do i need a trigger.

note I only want insert not update statement.

hope my question is clear, let me know how can i improve this more.

Comment: You do need an `update` if you are changing the current row with a new one (or a `DELETE` and `INSERT`, wich is what the `UPDATE` does anyway). On another note, what happens if you try to insert a dataset that contains multiple rows with the same `Seq`, wich one should be the chosen one?

Comment: Can multiple records with the same `Seq` value ever be inserted by the same `INSERT` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a single statement which will either insert or update the record based on the seqno. You could look into using [Merge](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use the merge statement. A good reference to it can be found here :

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

and an example can be found here

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking [for the `MERGE` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb510625.aspx), which enables you to do an "Upsert": an insert or update in a single statement (although you still need to be slightly careful with lock handling, see http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx

If you literally want to use an `INSERT`, I don't think there is a way of doing what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

its not a merge, the data is on the same table
you would need a INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger

In this case I chose to delete the existing row if seq exists.
If it doesn't fits you, you can do an update, I just rather this way because you will always have to insert the new row

```
create trigger myTrigger
on myTable
instead of insert
as
begin
  declare @seq int

  select @seq = seq from inserted
  if exists (select 1 from myTable where seq= @seq) begin
    delete from myTable where seq=@seq
  end
  insert into myTable
  select * from inserted
end
```

Comment: This assumes that only one record is inserted at a time

Comment: yes it does. He did not mentioned otherwise. It can be updated to deal with more than one row, if necessary.